# Push notification will not work on production

Tags: ios, objective-c

My app is all already up and live at the app store!

Before i uploaded it i checked the push notification on the development, and everything worked perfectly fine (it still works on the development Cer).

I tried to re generating the certificate several times with this tutorial, that in the past always worked for me :https://pushio.zendesk.com/entries/21644287-generating-a-pem-file-for-ios
Same as the provision files. 
I checked the bundle name to see its all the same.

I'm out of ideas what else to do, is there is no ether way ill change the code in the app it self, and ask for an update. but even then i do not know what else to change!

Any advice will be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Have you switched from the development server address to the production one ?

Comment: may it help :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12447025/how-to-test-production-push-notifications?rq=1

Comment: Which server side language you are using? Test it again with production .pem/.p12 key. So you will get to know where is the problem server side or certificate problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for these:

1-gatway for

`Developer   :gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com, port 2195`.
`Distribution :gateway.push.apple.com, port 2195`

2-Check that push notification is enable in your distribution profile.

Comment: 2 - Checked 1 - Were do i see this? " Developer   :gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com, port 2195. Distribution :gateway.push.apple.com, port 2195" is it at actual document?

Comment: which push code service you are using.? Is it there in server side push code.

Comment: yes these gateway are mention in apple site.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ProvisioningDevelopment.html