# Push notifications stop working after packaging iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apn

I have an enterprise iOS app I'm developing which receives push notifications for various features. I have the push notification service installed and working while debugging the app with Xcode and an iPhone X (phone doesn't matter, I've tried multiple and they all seem to work directly from Xcode).

If I package the app and distribute it over the air to the device, I get the normal "Would you like to receive push notifications" (which I agree to), but then it won't receive push notifications.

Things I've checked:

- Make sure the device capability "Push Notifications" is turned on.
- Make sure the bundle identifier matches.
- Verify that the pushID is correct.
- Verify that Background Modes: Remote Notifications is turned on.

The only thing I can think of is that maybe when the app is packaged it's flipping something to production rather than development and maybe when I send the push notification it's not able to send to production or something along those lines.

Has anyone had this issue before?

Comment: are you sure when you package app the profile is development or production

Comment: Agree with @HarshalBhavsar and I would also check the certificate

Comment: @HarshalBhavsar Thanks for the tip. I tried packaging the app for development and installing that way and it still isn't working. I remember a couple years ago with a different push notification service, needing a separate development and distribution certificate for push. I'm using a php service I wrote myself that only uses one certificate, could that be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@HarshalBhavsar's answer got me closer. I found the explanation here though:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35628480/3921182

As it turns out, Apple has a push notification service for development that is separate from distribution(production). When sending the push notification messages to a distributed app, they actually need to be sent to:

**ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195**
rather than
**ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195**

Comment: you have to use different .p12 for dev and production.
Also as u said different ssl

Comment: For enterprise development there's actually an option now for a combined .p12 which covers development and distribution which is kind of nice but also adds a level of confusion to everything haha. Thanks for all the help @HarshalBhavsar