# App crash when using test flight

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, testflight

Finally I finish my application so it is time to make some beta test. So I upload my application to itunes connect to test it out with test flight, but it keep crashing when I perform few task.

1. When I try to open the app from downloaded menu in test flight app.
2. When I try make a http request with AFnetworking
3. When I insert new record to `CoreData`
4. Sometime when i open the app from test flight it did not crash but show me a black screen after lauch screen.

I have been searching for 5 day without any clue. I been test it out with both release and debug mode running from xcode it doesn't crash at all. The problem only occur on if the app install from testflight. I think might be some memory allocated issues. It is a bug from testflight? How can I make the same behaviour happening at test flight happen in my xcode as well to know and fix the error.

I'm targeting ios 8.0 ++

Testing on iphone 7 plus(ios 10.2) and iphone 5s(ios 9.3).

Xcode 8.3.2

I get alot of difference crash report but most of it similiar to this one. Maybe I insert some nil value into dictionary? But why does it not happen when I build it from xcode.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x18319ee38 __exceptionPreprocess + 124
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x182803f80 objc_exception_throw + 56
2   CoreFoundation                  0x183084554 -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:] + 924
3   Cellecter                       0x1001db19c 0x100040000 + 1683868
4   Cellecter                       0x1001dafe4 0x100040000 + 1683428
5   CoreFoundation                  0x183140eac __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 20
6   CoreFoundation                  0x1831406cc _CFXRegistrationPost + 396
7   CoreFoundation                  0x18314044c ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 60
8   CoreFoundation                  0x1831a9494 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1532
9   CoreFoundation                  0x18307e788 _CFXNotificationPost + 368
10  Foundation                      0x183adfd1c postQueueNotifications + 684
11  CoreFoundation                  0x1831547b0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
12  CoreFoundation                  0x183152554 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372
13  CoreFoundation                  0x183152884 __CFRunLoopRun + 672
14  CoreFoundation                  0x18307cd10 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
15  GraphicsServices                0x184964088 GSEventRunModal + 180
16  UIKit                           0x188351f70 UIApplicationMain + 204
17  Cellecter                       0x1001e8834 0x100040000 + 1738804
18  libdyld.dylib                   0x182c1a8b8 start + 4
```

Updated: some how the my first and fourth question have been fix Now my question narrow it down to crashing when try to insert record into afnetworking.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a lot of things.

It can be a migration issue with `CoreData`, a `ManagedObjectContext` issue.

The blackscreen could be a view issue.

Your question is too broad, we don't have code, we don't know your recent development.

Are you using real devices ? Emulators ? Which version of Xcode ? iOS deployment target ?

Please refer to this post next time you ask a question.

[How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I manage to fix the error, thx you for reply I giving u an upvote =)

Answer (score 1):

I finally manage to fix the issues. Actually the issues is quite simple, I will not be able to fix the issues if I don't symbolicate my crash report, actually the issues is on FCM, From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24044298/why-push-notifications-is-not-working-on-testflight) specifically say I need a production push certificate in order to receive the device token. Which the device token return nil every time and I attempt save the token to core data.

Comment: Glad you found the issue by yourself :)