# Twilio programmable voice: Do I need to rekey Mobile Push Credentials when changing from sandbox to live?

Tags: ios, twilio, callkit

As usual this twilio thingy is always painful, sometimes it works sometime it doesn't.

My app is on test flight, I've unchecked "Use this credential for sending to a sandbox APN".

In past it did work now it doesn't work.

My question is do I need to enter Certificate and Private Key again when switching from sandbox to Live mode or just unchecking "Use this credential for sending to a sandbox APN" will be sufficient.

I've done some searching but as usual no one knows exact answer. At some  place they say to renter cert and key and at some place it's said just uncheck the tick box.

What's correct way to fix this annoying issue?

[image: Twilio settings]

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

From what I understand about push notification certificates they can either be generated for and used with the APNS sandbox or for production.

Therefore, if you had previously generated these credentials for the sandbox then they won't work with a deployed application. ([This answer says that apps in Testflight need to use the production push environment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24045250/28376).)

You should create a new set of credentials using a new production certificate and key. You can then use those credentials for your production application. That way you retain the sandbox credentials so that you can continue to test on your development version of the app.

Side note: I'm sorry you've found Twilio to be a bit painful. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: My question was simple. Certificate and private keys are already entered. Can I tick/untick "Use this credential for sending to a sandbox APN" to switch between sandbox and production or not?

Comment: The certificate and keys can't work across both sandbox and production, so no. I imagine that check box is editable in case you select the wrong option first.