# Regarding about Push Notification

Tags: ios, push-notification

Actually, my app getting push notification in sandbox environment but when testing on production it is not working what is the issue is anybody faced the issue

Comment: You can visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12447025/how-to-test-production-push-notifications

Comment: thanks for the reply Mukesh so i would test on adhoc version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using adHoc profile that means this ipa is testing for specific team or testers (internal/external).

And when you want to submit your app to appstore you need to create **Distribution** certificates.

See more reference here,

https://developers.connectycube.com/ios/how-to-create-apns-certificate

https://support.magplus.com/hc/en-us/articles/203808748-iOS-Creating-a-Distribution-Certificate-and-p12-File

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm every steps creating push notification certificate for production environment.

You can follow detailed steps here:

[Generate .pem file Used to setup Apple PUSH Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250510/generate-pem-file-used-to-setup-apple-push-notification)