# APNS iOS device token

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, apple-push-notifications

I have a problem: I didn't receive push notification in AD_HOC app version.(through crashlitycs) But I tested and I know that the device tokens in both environments are equal (development and AD HOC).How can it be?What can I do?
I have checked everything, but didn't understand how device tokens can be equal.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ad Hoc builds will require your provider to use the production apns certificate and not the sandbox ssl certificate.

Reference: [what kind of certificate do I need to test apns using ad-hoc distribution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889743/what-kind-of-certificate-do-i-need-to-test-apns-using-ad-hoc-distribution)

Comment: Thanks, yes,i am using production certificate, i connected to APNS production server(not sandbox) successful, but notifications are not received. Device tokens on both AD_HOC and Dev provisions are equal.How can it be?